# Tmux color palette is not the same as the terminal emulator's

Tags: tmux, colors, gnome-terminal

I am running the following:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Gnome Terminal
- Tmux 2.6
- Vim 8.0.1453

When running the following snippet,

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    s="/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\"; s=s s s s s s s s;
    for (colnum = 0; colnum<77; colnum++) {
        r = 255-(colnum*255/76);
        g = (colnum*510/76);
        b = (colnum*255/76);
        if (g>255) g = 510-g;
        printf "\033[48;2;%d;%d;%dm", r,g,b;
        printf "\033[38;2;%d;%d;%dm", 255-r,255-g,255-b;
        printf "%s\033[0m", substr(s,colnum+1,1);
    }
    printf "\n";
}'
```

I get a continuous color band when outside of Tmux, as opposed to when I run it inside Tmux.

**`.tmux.conf`**

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:Tc"
```

I also tried setting the second option to

- `set -as terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color*:RGB"`
- `set -as terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color*:Tc"`
- `set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color*:RGB"`
- `set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color*:Tc"`
- `set -as terminal-overrides ",*256*:Tc"`

... and many more. I also tried removing the first setting altogether.

On a similar note, when running Vim inside Tmux with `set termguicolors` in `.vimrc`, I lose all colors.

The bottom line is that I cannot achieve what is referred to as "**true color**" in Tmux.

I am aware that there are many similar questions, but none offered a solution so far.

Comment: What does running `tmux show -s terminal-overrides` and `tmux info|grep Tc` inside tmux actually show? Are you sure you restarted tmux entirely after changing .tmux.conf? RGB was not added until tmux 2.7, so you will need to use Tc.